# How to display the values of array in sequence in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sequences

I need to display array in sequence

```
my array

Array
(
 [0] => test@yahoo.com
 [1] => rans@yahoo.com
 [2] => maria@gmail.com
 [3] => lspap@gmail.com
 [6] => sage@yahoo.com
 [7] => rlope@hotmail.com
 [13] => alyssa@gmail.com
)
```

I want output like following

```
Array
(
 [0] => test@yahoo.com
 [1] => rans@yahoo.com
 [2] => maria@gmail.com
 [3] => lspap@gmail.com
 [4] => sage@yahoo.com
 [5] => rlope@hotmail.com
 [6] => alyssa@gmail.com
)
```

Now my question is how can display array like above sequence in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex an array

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Well that answer has been given ca. four years ago or so.

Answer (score 0):

To display the values in sequence use a foreach loop as so

```
foreach($array as $arr){
 echo $arr."\n";
}
```

to store the values with new indexes or keys use

```
array_values($array);
```